# Как получить данные из Firebase Realtime Database при старте приложения

Tags: java, android, firebase, splash-screen

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой при работе с Firebase подскажите в чём загвоздка:

В упрощенном виде, моё приложение при загрузке должно обратиться в Realtime Database  и загрузить из неё URL адреса и отобразить их в простом WebView. Логично сделать эту операцию во время демонстрации SplashScreen.

Логика следующая

1. Стартует SplashActivity, получает URL-адреса и сохраняет из в локальном хранилище (статические поля в классе AppInfo).
2. SplashActivity запускает MainActivity
3. MainActivity получает URL из локального хранилища и отображает их в WebView.

Проблема в том, что если обращаться к Firebase из SplashActivity, то получаю :
`com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: Client is offline`

реализовал так:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "SplashActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        getDataFromDB();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        startMainActivity();
    }

    private void getDataFromDB() {
        FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child(AppInfo.APP_ID)  //пути к объектам проверены
                .child(AppInfo.APP_URLS)//проблема не в них
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isComplete()) {
                            HashMap<String, String> result = (HashMap) task.getResult().getValue();
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: result.get(AppInfo.HOME) = " + result.get(AppInfo.HOME));
                            AppInfo.HOME_URL = result.get(AppInfo.HOME);
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "FB onComplete: Fail!!!");
                            task.getException().printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void startMainActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
}
```

Что пробовал:

1. Увеличивал задержку между обращением к базе и стартом MainActivity (нет результата);
2. Стартовал MainActivity из метода onComplete() (иногда срабатывало, но в большинстве случаев просто останавливалась. Что собственно и логично);
3. Всякие танцы с бубном (нет результата);
4. Повешал копию метода getDataFromDB() на кнопку в MainActivity. Работает - загружает данные из Firebase и записывает их в лок.хранилище без проблем. (но этот вариант не соответствует логике приложения), однако если вызывать его не кнопкой, а из onCreate или onStart получаем тот же exception: client offline ;

Подскажите, как организовать стабильное обращение к Firebase RD в момент старта приложения?

Answer (score 0):

Вам не надо загрузить данные в SplashActivity, так как SplashActivity живёт всего лишь несколько секунд (по идее).
И потом зачем вам сохранить в БД? В MainActivity скачайте и покажите. Кроме того у Firebase RD есть offline mode.
А насчёт ошибки `com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: Client is offline` скорее всего вы обращайтесь на неправильный путь.

Comment: "так как SplashActivity живёт всего лишь несколько секунд" поэтому данные и помещаются в класе хранилище на базе статических полей. "скорее всего вы обращайтесь на неправильный путь." если метод скопировать и повешать на кнопку в MainActivity он прекрасно все загружает, а вот если вызвать его из onCreate или onStart, то данные не загружаются а имеем exception: client offline. СУТЬ вопроса "Как организовать стабильное обращение к Firebase RD в момент старта приложениия"